# Is there an algorithm to achieve optimal compression in a "streamed" manner, assuming equal probability of each possibility?

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, entropy

<sup>(Sorry for the question title; edits are welcome.)</sup>

Let's say that you have a set of data made of repeating units, consisting of a value with $2$ possibilities, a value with $3$ possibilities, $5$ possibilities, $4$ possibilities, repeat. The total number of possibilities per unit is $2\times3\times5\times4=120\text{ possibilities}$. Assuming that these are all equally probable, that's $\log_2120\approx6.9\text{ bits}$. This means that the minimum space required to represent $1$ unit is $1\text{ Byte}$, but the minimum space required to represent $1000$ units is $864\text{B}$.

The naïve way of producing this compression would be to put them all into a base-120 number, then convert this to binary. However, this requires having access to *all of the data* at once in order to decompress it. There must<sup>[citation needed]</sup> be some algorithm that can take in a stream of compressed data, output a stream of decompressed data, and only use finite memory, but I can't find one.

Please describe and explain such an algorithm, if one exists.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Huffman codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)?

Comment: @dkaeae Yes, but that assumes a fixed number of symbols with variable probability. This has a variable number of symbols with a fixed probability... or at least a fixed number of symbols with a fixed probability.

Comment: Consider just encoding 8 `unit`s in 7 `byte`s each, for a total of 875 bytes, a waste of 11 bytes or 12.6‰, but you gain "random access".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this requires having access to all of the data at once in order to decompress it.

Not true. The trick is to compress *backwards*, from the last symbol, to the first. You do need all the data at once to *compress* though.

However, what you are looking for can be done with *arithmetic coding*, without even needing access to all of the data at once during compression.

Comment: I'm not quite sure _how_ it can be done with arithmetic coding; after reading the Wikipedia article it seems to have [this problem too](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102399/is-there-an-algorithm-to-achieve-optimal-compression-in-a-streamed-manner-ass/102420#comment218629_102399)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Arithmetic coding allows you to change the probability table for each symbol encoded. So for the first symbol you use a table with 2 probabilities, then one with 3, etc.